# Match CSS until another match occurs

Tags: html, css, hover

What I'm trying to accomplish is a generic way to make something become visible only when a parent is being hovered on. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kRsG/1/

Markup here:

```
<div class="hover-parent">
    <div class="container">
        Hello world!
        <div class="hover-only">
            <h1>You're hovering container 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-parent">
            <div class="container-2">
                <div class="hover-only">
                    <h2>You're Hovering container 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS here:

```
.hover-parent:hover .hover-only {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hover-only {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

So, it's pretty simple, and it works unless you nest a `hover-parent` in another `hover-parent` the nested `hover-only` gets shown even though it's direct parent is not being hovered over.

So, to sum up, I want the `You're Hovering container 2` to only appear when I'm hovering over `container-2` and not when I'm hovering over `container`. Is this possible with CSS only (as in, no JavaScript/jQuery/etc. and not dependant on how the html is structured).

Comment: Me thinks you'd be better off with a different class for nested elements.

Comment: @adeneo, good idea. I'm using stylus anyway, so I don't have to copy/paste a bunch of css. I think that I'll have `hover-parent-<number>` and `hover-only-<number>` pairs. That'll work pretty well. If you want to make an answer, I'd accept that. Thanks!

Comment: Write your own answer, outlining how you solved the issue in a way that can be helpful to others searching for this, and accept that. And remember to upvote the others that have posted working answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in CSS without some sort of dependency on the DOM structure. So what I ended up doing was the following stuff:

Because I use Stylus, I was able to do this:

```
for layer in 1 .. 10
  .hover-parent-{layer}
    .hover-only-{layer}
      opacity 0
      transition opacity 0.2s
    &:hover
      .hover-only-{layer}
        opacity 1
```

This produces the following CSS

```
.hover-parent-1 .hover-only-1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.hover-parent-1:hover .hover-only-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hover-parent-2 .hover-only-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.hover-parent-2:hover .hover-only-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* etc... */
```

And then I can simply do:

```
<div class="hover-parent-1">
  <h1 class="hover-only-1">This is container 1</h1>
  <div class="container hover-parent-2">
    <h2>This will always show up</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="as-many-as-i-want">
        <i class="icon-awesome hover-only-2"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

direct descendent selector

```
.hover-parent:hover > div > .hover-only {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note: this assumes you have exactly one level of `<div>` between `hover-parent` and `hover-only` so you may need to adjust it if that's not valid

Comment: +1 because it's the way to do it and I didn't understand why someone downvoted this.

Comment: That works, but now it's not really a "general way" to do this any longer, as it's very dependant on markup

Comment: use this then `[class^=hover-parent]:hover  > [class^=container] >.hover-only`

Answer (score 3):

For unlimited nest a hover-parent, "general way" and independant on markup better use this

```
[class^=hover-parent]:hover  > [class^=container] >.hover-only {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8kRsG/3/)

adding a child

```
<div class="hover-parent">
    <div class="container">
        Hello world!
        <div class="hover-only first">
            <h1>You're hovering container 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-parent">
            <div class="container-2">
                <div class="hover-only second">
                    <h2>You're Hovering container 2</h2>
                </div>
                      <div class="hover-parent">
                           <div class="container-3">
                              <div class="hover-only third">
                              <h2>You're Hovering container 3</h2>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8kRsG/5/)

UPDATE: use the Universal selector based on what you want to achive

```
[class^=hover-parent]:hover  > [class^=container] >.hover-only,
[class^=hover-parent]:hover  > [class^=container]  >*  >.hover-only{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/8kRsG/8/)

Comment: Wow, awesome! I'm pretty sure this will work for me! It may be necessary for me to need to have a `hover-parent` inside another `hover-only`. Is that possible?

Comment: yes it it just post a fiddle of your markup i will do the css depending on your needs

Comment: why not? just use classes

Comment: If I wrap the .hover-only.third in another div, it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/8kRsG/6/

Comment: Sorry, that's still dependant on the markup. I'm thinking this is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Stephen's answer is correct. If you're still not sure how to approach it, try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwankyLegg/8kRsG/2/).

If it still doesn't work for you, just make sure you're selecting all the way down.

```
.activate-hover:hover > .show-on-hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Also, it may be a function of your HTML not being structured in a way that makes sense for your style rules.